# NoMethodError: undefined method, but I have never called the method; member is just a column in my users schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I never call the member method but for some reason every time I try to create a user it gives me this error`` NoMethodError: undefined method `member' for #<User:0x007fb6210e4c08> ``

Here is my db schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161102184628) do
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "fname"
    t.string   "lname"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "phone",           limit: 8
    t.integer  "housenum"
    t.string   "street"
    t.string   "town"
    t.string   "state"
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "member"
    t.string   "payType"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

end
```

Here is my user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
 validates(:fname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 15 })
 validates(:lname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 15 })
 VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
 validates(:email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }, format: { with:      VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false })
 validates(:phone, presence: true, uniqueness: true)
 validates(:housenum, presence: true, length: { maximum: 5 })
 validates(:street, presence: true, length: { maximum: 15 })
 validates(:town, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 })
 validates(:state, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20})
 validates(:member, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20})
 validates(:payType, presence:true, length: { maximum: 20} )
 has_secure_password
 validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

I get this error every time I try to create a new user in the console.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that schema really matches what's in your database? BTW, every time you try to create a `User` you will be calling the `member` method because you're validating its presence.

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out that validation does everything else still work?

It would be worth making sure that your console is running against the same environment as you have migrated that DB for.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when there is a NoMethodError relating to an attribute of a class, it means your database is clinging to an old version of that model/migration that does not have that attribute.

Perhaps try deleting your schemas.rb, running rake db:drop, and then running rake db:create / rake db:migrate again?

Comment: Answer is not complete without an example or more definite statement.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, neither `rails c` or `rails s` give you any warning about pending migrations in the console. My immediate thought is that you have a migration that adds the `member` field (or similar) pending, and that's why Rails doesn't recognise the field yet - it hasn't been migrated in.

So, just to make sure, run your migrations:

```
$ rails db:migrate
```

and try again.

The reason you're getting this error even when you don't call the `User#member` method explicitly is that your validations are validating the presence of the field, which by necessity has to call the method to get the value.

Comment: I do not have a User#member method. Does this mean I need to make one? Also, if I need to make one for member, do I need to make a method for every other field, like town, and state? Also, I believe the migrations are up to date.

Comment: @karthikchid If your User has a `member` field, you have a `User#member` method (as long as you've run the migrations). Even if you believe the migrations are up to date, I suggest running the command anyway to make sure.